# C# Application fails depending on which PC was used to compile it

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, telerik

A colleague has made a C# Windows Forms application using Telerik controls. The application runs on computer "User" when compiled on computer "DevA", but not when compiled on computer "DevB".

The "User" Windows Event Log for the version that does not compile looks like:

```
Application: OptionCeaserTool.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException

Stack:
   at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveType(System.Reflection.RuntimeModule, Int32, IntPtr*, Int32, IntPtr*, Int32, System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ObjectHandleOnStack)
   at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandleInternal(System.Reflection.RuntimeModule, Int32, System.RuntimeTypeHandle[], System.RuntimeTypeHandle[])
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveType(Int32, System.Type[], System.Type[])
```

I assume that computer "DevB" includes a reference that cannot be resolved at run type.  Is that correct?  If so, how could we figure out what type is causing the problem?

Comment: Are you using some from of source control? And if you are, are you sure you have checked in all the source code? Also is there a difference in architecture on the two different machines, such as x86 and x64? One last thing, are you using the same versions of `Telerik`, it might be that you could possible have a patch installed on the one machine but not the other.

Comment: you need to make sure that all refrenced dll's are copied next to the exe (specially look for Telerik's dll's) my guess some dll's are missing

Comment: you can use http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx for advanced monitoring to know what is the file that is requested by the software and not found

Comment: Why you believe that a telerik dll is missing? Have you some log that refers to telerik?

Comment: i had this kind of problem before at an external control dll that was missing

Comment: We use TFS and both Dev PC's have run "Get Latest".  Builds from both PC's include the same Telerik DLLs, and one of them works.  I've used procmon but its output doesn't contain obvious pointer

Comment: Did you debug it in Visual studio?

Comment: The Windows event log (application event log, as I recall) often has an entry that will give you more detail. You could of course do a directory comparison of the files produced by "DevA" and "DevB" during the build. Comparing sizes will probably tell you very quickly where the difference lies.

Comment: @JimMischel: If I run the executable in VS, it shows a "The type initializer for 'Tool.MainForm' threw an exception." error.

Comment: @Andomar Check the InnerException property of the TypeInitializationException; it is likely to contain information about the underlying problem, and exactly where it occurred.

Comment: @Matt: That pointed us to the offending assembly, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Matt's comment, we checked the InnerException.  There were five levels of inner exceptions.  The innermost contained the error:

> {"Could not load file or assembly 'Telerik.OpenAccess,
>   Version=2013.3.1320.1, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7ce17eeaf1d59342' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.":"Telerik.OpenAccess,
>   Version=2013.3.1320.1, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7ce17eeaf1d59342"}

There was no reference to this assembly in Visual Studio.   Since we figured the reference had to come from somewhere, we did a plain text search on the source directory.  This found the following line in the `.csproj` file:

```
<Import Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\OpenAccess.targets')"
        Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\OpenAccess.targets" />
```

This line existed both on DevA and DevB.  The line seems to import Telerik OpenAccess only when it is installed on the machine. When DevA compiled, the condition is true, so the executable ended up referring to `Telerik.OpenAccess`.  When DevB compiled, the condition was false, so no reference was included.

It seems that the project had been modified to remove `Telerik.OpenAccess`, but the `Import` directive had lingered behind.  The problem was solved by deleting the `Import` line from the `.csproj`. Now the tool works when compiled on either machine.

Answer (score 0):

There is some file (probably a dll) that the system cannot find.  It is attempting to use reflection to find the file, and cannot.  You're the only one who can determine what file it is that is missing.  Is it telling you a line number and class that the problem exists at?

Comment: The app silently crashes.  The windows event log does not give me a line number or class.